# webview 2 icon not displayed in Visual Studio toolbox

Tags: c++, visual-studio, webview2

For some reason, and after trying all the solutions that i found on the internet, the Webview 2 tool isn't showing in the Toolbox.

I have installed and upgraded Visual Studio, Microsoft Edge and Microsoft Edge Canary, but nothing seem to help.

i am using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.7.2

Webview 2 9.538 (Pre-release, as suggested in one of the answers, i have tried all other versions also).

i have downloaded and installed Edge Canary version 87.0.629.0.

the version of Edge is "85.0.564.44‏".

any idea ?

‏

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using and for your UI framework are you using WPF, WinForms, or something else? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. my Project Properties, indicates that i'm using .NET Target Framework Version 4.7.2. Common Language runtime support (/clr). i'm using forms. I must say that i'm a c developer, but need to build GUI so i'm using C++ for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would like to share with you the solution:

i have added the component manually:

inside toolbox menu -> right click anywhere -> choose items -> browse -> project name -> packages - > webView 2 folder -> lib -> net462 -> Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll

disclaimer:

I have tried this solution with other (newer) webView 2 releases, but it didn't work (as specified in the question i'm using v.9.538 (Pre-release).

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.